# iOS App - Failed to create provisioning profile

Tags: ios, iphone, ios11, provisioning-profile, xcode9

I was updating iPhone app after iOS 11 release. I got an build error while trying to archive the app with Generic device. The error is

> "Failed to create provisioning profile. The appID XX cannot be
>   registered to your development team. Change your bundle identifier to
>   a unique string and try again."

I cannot change the bundle identifier, even though it can solve the problem [When changing the bundle identifier, i am getting error because of "No device registered"]. I have a developer account, through which previous versions of app were developed, however old versions were developed in another mac machine.

I am using Xcode 9.2 Also in the account added, i could not see "View details" below my account in Xcode 9.2 as shown in various apple guide for Xcode.

Any help is appreciated.

Comment: Does the apple developer account your signed in as own the app ID you are trying?  It does not appear so.  Basically what the error is telling you is that you are trying to build for an app ID that some other developer account has already registered.  Is your new developer account a free developer account?  Is it a team member on a paid account?

Answer (score 1):

You should visit apple's developer portal here:

https://developer.apple.com/

On the top right, select "Account"

After login in, go to "Certificates, IDs & Profiles" on the left.

Then under the Provisioning Profiles section, make sure the one you are using for your current app (Developer one if its a wild card, or Your App Name if it is using entitlements) has your current user account registered in it.

You can download it and double click it after and it will be automatically added to Xcode.

Answer (score 0):

The only solution for now is change the bundle indentifier